# How to prevent the value of an array from changing

Tags: java, arrays, static, multidimensional-array

In my program, I am declaring a static int 2D array and setting it equal to some values. In a different method, I create a local variable and assign it to the 2D array I created. I make some changes to the local variable, however I don't want my initial values in my 2D array to change.
The reason I am using static is because I am using a static main method and I figured all other methods and variables had to be static as well.

Here's a simple layout of what I am doing

```
public static int[][] myArray = {{1,2},{3,4}};

public static void main(String args[]){
    doSomething();
}

public static void doSomething(){
    int[][] newArray = myArray;

    //do Something to newArray

}
```

I do not want the values of myArray to change is there a way to handle this? Do I have to get rid of a static variable within a static method?

Comment: You have to deep copy whole array into new one.

Comment: @Antoniossss how would I go by doing that

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create deep copy of your array. You can do it manually or use [System.arraycopy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to suit your needs.

Comment: Manually you mean just create that new array and assign each value in the old array to it?

Comment: Yes, that would be one way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are mutable and so you need to use System.arraycopy to make defensive copies. Make the array private and call a public method which hands a copy is the way to prevent mistakes of bugs by sharing a reference when you must not.

Answer (score 1):

Deep copy the original one and keep one of these two arrays (only making change to one of them

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int[][] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(myArray, myArray.length)
```